# ADT Bundle .bashrc $PATH not working

Tags: bash, android, bashrc

I Installed the ADT bundle, worked fine the first go, even from a Gnome custom launcher.  Didn't test ADB or FASTBOOT from CL, subsequently neither nor ADT is working.

```
echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/:
/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/
```

Path is correct, /opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/.

Not sure what I've done wrong?  Every guide I've read has the same path to export.

**EDIT**

Path appears to be working;

```
dave@helios:/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools$ ls -l
total 2140
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dave dave 1231255 Jan 26 08:00 adb
drwxr-xr-x 2 dave dave    4096 Jan 26 08:00 api
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dave dave  197736 Jan 26 08:00 fastboot
-rw-r--r-- 1 dave dave  727806 Jan 26 08:00 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 dave dave   16648 Jan 26 08:00 source.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 dave dave    4096 Jan 26 08:00 systrace

dave@helios:/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools$ adb
bash: /opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory

dave@helios:/opt/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools$
```

Comment: open .bashrc and add path to that file at the end

Comment: Pretty much, it's already there as echoed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the case where you're trying to run a 32 bit ELF binary, on a 64 bit install, without having the 32 bit libraries installed. If that's the case, installing the package named ia32-libs should let you run this adb binary.

Comment: Cheers.  Using 13.10, ia32-libs has no installation candidate.

Comment: And found the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523502/androids-aapt-not-running-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-no-ia32-libs-how-can-i-fix    Cheers.

Comment: @DaveC Ah, so it's done differently from 13.10 and onwards. Good to know for future issues of this kind.